# How can I improve my question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

My recent [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/699883/buck-regulators-feedback-voltage-far-lower-than-expected) about my buck regulator output was closed for "needs detail or clarity" but I don't know what details I should add to this question to fix that. I have a specific problem/question so it shouldn't be about clarity, and I tried to list all of the details that one would need to help. Can anyone provide me with some idea as to what else I can add to reopen this question?

Also, I don't really get *why* this was closed. I had already responded to one person who asked for additional info and edited my question to include said info, so clearly I was willing to engage with comments and provide more details. Why VTC instead of asking me for the details that would have made it a better question? And what can I do different next time so this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The question is not specific enough, please be more speicfic on what you need help with. It looks more like "here is my buck design help me with the problem" It would be nice to see a specific question on where your understanding is falling short or an aspect of the design that you need help with.

Comment: Thanks for the answer here. I think my problem is that I'm new to these circuits, so I'm not really sure where to start. I thought I had been clear about my specific problem being my Vout/Vfb measuring way lower than expected, but I will try to make it more clear what I'm having trouble with.

Comment: And honestly I guess it kind of is a "heres my buck design, help me" question. I'm willing to do the work, would be just as happy getting an answer that tells me what other values to check or where to start the debugging process as opposed to one that tells me what's wrong - I just don't know enough to do that on my own I guess. I'm doing a deep dive into some resources rn in hopes of solving this on my own as well, but figured I'd complement that with a post in case anyone had insight. Sounds like I should try to make future posts a little more focused.

Comment: If you ask a good question, you get good answers.

Comment: Well I made changes to (hopefully) make my question better and ended up getting a good answer, so proved your point pretty quickly. Appreciate your input a ton :)